# Using RequestStreamHandler for multiple event sources and split on batch failures

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis

I have a use case(**Scenario 1**) where I have a `lambda` which listens to `kinesis streams` from `DynamoDB` changes, if there is an error while processing any record in the batch of `kinesis stream` I return the `sequence number` of the record back so that the batch can be split(as mentioned over [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html#services-kinesis-batchfailurereporting)) and since I have defined the `max retries`, after the retries are exhausted the failed record goes to `SQS`.

This SQS also we are planning to have it as event source of the same above lambda(**Scenario 2**). Now the issue is, in case of single event source of `KDS`(**Scenario 1**) I was using `RequestHandler` and for batch failure I was returning the `sequence number of failed record` in the `StreamEventResponse`. In **Scenario 2**, I am using `RequestStreamHandler` since I have multiple event sources(KDS and SQS) and I am writing the `sequence number of failed record` as below in the `OutputStream`. However it looks like `Lambda` is not treating it as failure and not performing any retries. Is there a way to achieve **scenario 2** using `RequestStreamHandler` where I can return the `seq number for lambda to retry`?

**Scenario 2 where KDS and SQS are the event sources for the same lambda**

```
 public void handleRequest(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Context context) throws IOException
{

      final byte[] byteArray= IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
      String request= new String(byteArray, StandardCharSets.UTF_8);
      KinesisEvent kinesisEvent=new ObjectMapper.readValue(request,KinesisEvent.class);
      String seqNo= kinesisEvent.getRecords().get(0).getKinesis().getSequenceNumber();
      List<StreamEventResponse.BatchItemFailure> batchItemFailures = new ArrayList();
      batchItemFailures.add(new StreamEventResponse.BatchItemFailure(seqNo));
      byte[] failures = SerializationUtils.serialize(new StreamEventResponse(batchItemFailures));

      output.write(failures); 


}
```